# Java EE -- using the same stateful object for several users

Tags: concurrency, jakarta-ee, ejb, stateful

Even though I've been in Java SE for quite some time now, I started EE & web w/ Java only about a month ago, so pardon if the question seems a bit noobish...

So here's the situation: I'm trying to write a JS based multi-player game with real-time interaction (let's say chess in this example, though it really doesn't matter what particular game it is, could be tennis or w/ever). The clients would interact with the server through JS calls, sending the move etc. Now, while I could just receive the move from one client & pass it straight on to the other player, not maintaining the game state on the server would mean putting a huge sign out saying "user JS scripts welcome" (and that's out of experience -- "hacked" a crapload of that kind myself). This brings me to my problem -- how do I share a stateful object between several sessions? One idea that came to mind was a singleton storing a Hashmap of stateful beans & then each session could retrieve the bean by it's hash, but I've no idea how right that is (and it seems rather complex for a fairly common thing like that). Tieing it to application scope seems overkill as well...

P.S. I do understand that the object would need concurrency managing etc, I just can't seem to put my finger on how to get it shared...

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't mention it before -- using Glassfish, EE6.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Shared it via ServletContext, which I initially thought wouldn't work 'cause FacesServlet is a separate one, thought it has smthn like a different container either.

Comment: @Mike The question is more than 2 years old now, don't even really remember what it was about. :) Will see if I can get a decent write-up over the weekend for it though, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a business process scenario which is defined according to Seam framework documentation as follows

> The business process **spans multiple interactions with multiple users, so this state is shared between multiple users, but in a well-defined manner**. The current task determines the current business process instance, and the lifecycle of the business process is defined externally using a process definition language, so there are no special annotations for business process demarcation.

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/en-US/html/jbpm.html#d0e6976) you can see a Seam business process management Tutorial

Notice Seam uses [JBoss BPM](http://jboss.org/jbpm) behind the scenes to handle its business process context. **If you just want to use plain JBoss BPM capabilities**, you can see [here](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v4/devguide/html_single/#jbossintegration) how to integrate with JBoss

See also [JBoss BPM User guide](http://docs.jboss.com/jbpm/v4/userguide/html_single/)

Comment: Sorry, guess I should've mentioned it in the post in the beginning -- I'm using Glassfish & wanna stay that way, 'cause I'm pretty sure there's gotta be a way to get it done on GF as well...

Comment: @TC1 I see. One approach could be store your Stateful object in the application context (because session context is *per user*) with an unique id assigned to identity the game